# How do I clip an image in xaml and limit the image width? (Winrt)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime

I have an image that can get set through an api, I want the image to get clipped when it's wider than 250 px.  And that works.  However, the image is in a stackpanel along with some textblocks.  And even though what we see of the image is clipped, the actual image width remains over 250 px.

Here is the xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button Foreground="Black" Content="Button" x:Name="BackButton" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,0,0,0"  Click="BackButtonClick" />
                        <Border>
                            <Image x:Name="LogoImage" Source="Images/Logo.png" Height="50"  Margin="15 0 0 0" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image.Clip>
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0 0 50 250"></RectangleGeometry>
                                </Image.Clip>
                            </Image>

                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" x:Name="NameTextbox" Margin="15, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="26"></TextBlock>

                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="ErrorMessage" Text="Unable to reach server" Foreground="Red" Margin="15 0 0 0"  FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
```

So let's say that the image width is 2000 px.  Then the textblock after the image will get pushed off of the screen, but only 250 pixels of the image will be visible.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I gave up on clipping and used a scrollviewer.  If you disable scrolling then it clips the image and keeps whatever dimensions you set for the scrollviewer.  I actually left scrolling invisible in case anybody tries to scroll the image they can.  I pasted the code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I was taking the wrong approach.  I was able to achieve what I wanted using a scrollviewer with scrolling disabled.

```
<ScrollViewer MaxWidth="350" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
     <Image x:Name="LogoImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="Images/Logo.png" Height="50" Margin="15 0 0 0" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center">
     </Image>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the width and height of the border and setting Image Stretch to None and avoid using the heavy ScrollViewer.

Comment: That doesn't work for me because the height of the image isn't a guaranteed 50 px.  Which is the height that I need.  So the image has to be stretched uniformly based on the height.  Setting stretch to none would just clip the height and the width of the image.

Comment: Well, but you can still clip the border to its bounds and let the image inside it be bigger than the Border.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried @FilipSkakun's answer and it worked very well, with one adjustment: I put `Image.Stretch` to `UniformToFill`.

I'm posting my code here, as it may help someone:

```
<Border Width="30" Height="30">
    <Border.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15" Center="15,15" />
    </Border.Clip>
    <Image Source="..." VerticalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="30" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
</Border>
```

Plus, I can control the image positioning by the `VerticalAlignment` property.